# Calling ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent inside onActivityResult does not work on Android 5.0.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have a button handler that calls **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent.

```
  Intent intCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  intCamera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(IMAGE_PATH));
  startActivityForResult(intCamera, 1);
```

Inside onActivityResult I also call **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** to continue taking pictures.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Intent intCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intCamera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(IMAGE_PATH));
            startActivityForResult(intCamera, 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem with **ASUS** Android **ver. 5.0.0**

It starts of OK once fired inside the button handler, but once it is fired inside onActivityResult, somehow it will show a black camera screen then automatically stop. and I will receive a resultCode = 0 (Only happens in 5.0.0, I checked with 5.0.1 and it works and also in other succeeding versions).

It works though when I place delay on the intent inside onActivityResult before it is started but I'm not allowed to place a delay, I'm hoping if there is a flag or a method I could use to make this work.

I need to be able to shoot pictures continuously after clicking ok every shot. Bearing in mind that the solution should also support API8.